# MongoDB global lock: reading and inserting lots of data at the same time

Tags: mongodb, load, locking, timeout

I have a single MongoDB running for a rails 3 app (using mongoid adapter) on a Linux 64-bit box.  I'm doing a bulk upload of 1.5m records amounting to about 2GB of data.  I'm loading the data via rest calls to my app using a script I wrote (retrieves an individual record from the input files and inserts it into MongoDB one at a time).  This will work fine if I leave everything alone and do not query the DB.

However, during one load process, I queried the DB via my app and tried to retrieve ALL of the  records so far in MongoDB (about 700,000 at that time).  This resulted in a timeout for my loading script.

The question is, is it possible for MongoDB's global lock to stall the entire DB during the query while trying to insert data, resulting in the load script timing out?  I just need to know if it's possible.  I thought the global lock was different for read/writes.

I know the exact time may be different per system and config, but I'm trying to see if this is a feasible possibility so I can prepare accordingly for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Like most systems, a write lock has precedence over a read lock.

With the global lock you may have one writer *or* many readers

If you have a write lock active, read locks will queue up.

What does your disk look like underneath the system? That could also contribute to performance backups of reading and writing which would exacerbate the locking.

Answer (score -1):

First of all if you want to have some batch to load all data you can define different mongo connection than the rest of operations.
So your application can have several Mongo objects with different timeouts definition. 
In Mongo 2.0 they improved the locking and will improve it in mongo2.2
But this is alway the general problem you want some of reads operation be very fast, some of other reads slower and for write you can have different latencies definition.